# Why is there a Max width of a website of 960px instead of just making it a percentage of width?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, frontend, bulma

Bulma and I think Bootstrap have max widths on their media queries.

Why wouldn't you just make width a percentage of the screen size and leave it at that?

Comment: What do you mean "max widths"? Like `@media (max-width: 700px)`?

Comment: Yeah exactly. Wondering why have a max width for the various media queries when you can define a percentage width and it will stay that width the entire time?

Comment: But a percentage of what? There isn't really a "one-true-screen" that is the benchmark for all other screens.

Comment: Yeah but why wouldn't a percentage be ok, until you wanted to say drop into a mobile format with a media query.  I just don't quite get max width's for the entire site content.

Comment: Again, a percentage of what? For this to work on mobile you would need some reference screen size that doesn't change with the actual screen size. How is a min-width: 80% going to work when switching from Desktop to say a Tablet. How does the browser determine what 80% is. And how exactly do you achiever an 80% viewport on a mobile device when the browser is basically always in fullscreen mode? I'm just trying to understand how this is supposed to work without absolute pixels.

Answer (score 1):

Per [MDN's documentation on media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries#Media_features), there are only a few features dedicated to size: `width`, `height`, `device-width`, and `device-height`.

In the past, `device-width` and `device-heigth` was available for media queries, which could theoretically be sort of used for what you're attempting to do, but this has [since been deprecated](https://drafts.csswg.org/mediaqueries-4/#mf-deprecated) and must not be used in new code.

That leaves `width` and `height` which takes a "length" value.

Per [MDN's documentation on "length"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length), there is no length unit that corresponds to the screen/display.

There are "absolute length units" which are matched to real-life lengths whenever possible, or close approximations when not. For example, `1px` is 1/96th of an inch, or 1 device pixel on low-resolution screens.

There are "font-relative lengths" which are relative to the size of a particular character or font attribute in the current font. For example, `1em` is equal to the current font size of the element (or of the parent element when specified on the `font-size` property).

Finally, there are "viewport-percentage lengths", which are relative to the size of the viewport. While this is sometimes confused with the size of the screen/display, this is actually the size of the visible portion of the document: the part of the browser dedicated to displaying the webpage. So, `1vw` would be 1% of the width of the visible portion of the page, while `100vw` would be the width of the visible portion of the page. With iframes, the "viewport" is the size of the iframe. You can see this demonstrated below:

```html
<code style="background: yellow; display: block; width: 50vw; height: 50vh">
  background: yellow;<br>
  display: block;<br>
  width: 50vw;<br>
  height: 50vh
</code>
```

You can also use [percentages](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/percentage) in other places in CSS, but all these do are take the inherited value (parent's value) and multiply it by that percentage. That is, if the parent is `100px` wide and the child sets its width to `50%`, the child's width gets converted to `50px`. In the case of `(min|max)-(width|height)` on media queries, there is no parent to compare it to, but if they faked one, it would likely be the viewport, like `vw`, `vh`, and percentages on `html` use. However, browsers actually just completely ignore percentages on `(min|max)-(width|height)` as can be seen here:

```css
@media (min-width: 1%) {
  * { background: yellow }
}
@media (max-width: 100%) {
  * { background: red }
}
```

```html
<code style="display: block">
  @media (min-width: 1%) { div { background: yellow } }<br>
  @media (max-width: 100%) { div { background: red } }
</code>
```

There are also [resolution-related units](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/resolution) you can use with media queries (with `resolution`), but these are limited to the number of dots per length like `dpi` for dots per inch, not the total number of dots on the screen.

---

Media queries relating to the size of a screen wouldn't be all that helpful for the majority of use cases, however, as the biggest use case for `(min|max)-(width|height)` is for *different screen sizes*, such as phones, tablets, laptops, and large desktop displays. Having a `max-width: 50%` breakpoint on a `1920x1080` screen would mean the breakpoint would be around `960px`. On an iPhone XS, that same breakpoint would be around `207px` (CSS pixels, not device pixels). Most people won't be using browsers in split screen, and most (all?) phones don't support windowed mode or double split screen, so you would never hit breakpoints with both height and width set in percentages. And unless you were using percentages and items that could always wrap, you would have to specify additional information in each media query to be useful (eg, `(max-width: 50%) and (min-width: 50px)`).

What this *could* be helpful for is an app that used multiple windows for a single application. Think Photoshop or GIMP in windowed mode, as opposed to all of the toolbars being in a single window. But even then, any effects are likely still achieveable with existing media queries.

---

So, the answer to your question is we use non-percentage lengths because viewport breakpoints would never be triggered (viewport is always 100%) and resolution breakpoints (eg, percentage of screen size) don't exist. The one set of resolution breakpoint media queries available (`device-width` and `device-height`) are deprecated and must not be used in new code.

Instead, we use length breakpoints to change the design when the visible portion of the page is a different size, regardless of how large or small the device is.

Many libraries use absolute lengths (eg, `px`) instead of relative units (eg, `em`) due to the fact that most developers design based on pixels. Over time, there has been a shift toward relative units, but there hasn't been a tipping point.

While `960px` is pretty widespread, this desktop/tablet breakpoint has changed over time. For a long period of time, websites were designed to fit on a `1024x768` monitor. With the scrollbar and browser chrome (border around window) taken into account, websites were often designed at `1000px` wide, and later `980px` became common for reasons I can't remember, but I wouldn't be surprised if some operating system or browser came along that that had chrome and scrollbar width that added up to more than `24px`, or it might be related to a popular framework at the time using it. Anyway, when mobile devices became more popular, designing sites to work in grids also did, which is why [`960px` is so common nowadays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10538599/default-web-page-width-1024px-or-980px).

Comment: This is dopest evolution of this part of the css I've seen. Thank you! 

"Many libraries use absolute lengths (eg, px) instead of relative units (eg, em) due to the fact that most developers design based on pixels."

So the frameworks use these basically because there's an informal design standard built around these widths?

Comment: @mutant_city For the most part, yeah. At least for why they use `px` instead of `em` or similar. As for why they use `960px` specifically, that'd be due to the fact that `960` has [a lot of factors](https://www.mathwarehouse.com/answered-questions/factors/what-are-the-factors-of-960-solved.php), making it ideal for designing with a grid.

Answer (score 0):

the breakpoint values for the different display scales vary by a specific pixel depending to the fundamental that has been actually used like:

Small display scales - ( min-width: 576px) and ( max-width: 575px),

Medium screen scale - ( min-width: 768px) and ( max-width: 767px),

Large size display dimension - ( min-width: 591px) and ( max-width: 992px),

And Additional big display sizes - ( min-width: 1200px) and ( max-width: 1199px),

Comment: I think your answer is basically pretty good, but one of your examples, `( min-width: 992px) and ( max-width: 591px)` has a min-width that is greater than the max-width. You may want to correct that.

Comment: But just wondering why even have a max width when you can just define percentages for the dimensions?